# How can I get the key of the object with a lowest attribute value for a Python dictionary with a string as key and a class object as value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below, I want Python to print "Name: test1, Value: 4":

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        
test1 = Test("test1",4)
test2 = Test("test2",6)
testDictionary = {}
testDictionary["test1"] = test1
testDictionary["test2"] = test2

res = min(testDictionary, key=attrgetter('value'))
print("Name: ",res.name, " Value: ",res.value)
```

but instead I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

How change my code so that I can get the key of the value with the lowest 'value' attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Try changing:

```
res = min(testDictionary, key=attrgetter('value'))
```

To:

```
res = min(testDictionary.values(), key=attrgetter('value'))
```

### Explanation:

Just only doing `testDictionary` would be getting the minimum values from the keys, example:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> list(d)
['a', 'b']
>>> list(d.values())
[1, 2]
>>>
```

### Full code:

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        
test1 = Test("test1",4)
test2 = Test("test2",6)
testDictionary = {}
testDictionary["test1"] = test1
testDictionary["test2"] = test2

res = min(testDictionary.values(), key=attrgetter('value'))
print("Name: ", res.name, " Value: ", res.value)
```

Output:

```
Name:  test1  Value:  4
```

Comment: @CoolGuy Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).